# how to get app details which request camera in android

Tags: android, request, android-camera, background-service

I want to know the details of the apps which is requesting to use the device camera in android in a background service. Is there any way to know the details of the app that is creating a request to start the camera

Comment: This is not possible, except by creating your own build of the Android OS and creating a ROM mod.

Comment: do you want to know that when the other application actually start the camera application?

Comment: no i want to know which application is calling the camera